# Slash added when redirected and using # in my url - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel generates the link fine using:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('users' . '#section1') }}">Section 1</a>
```

It generates:

```
http://example.com/users#section1
```

But when link is clicked and I'm redirected, link now looks like this (slash added):

```
http://example.com/users#/section1
```

Not sure why is doesn't stay like this:

```
http://example.com/users#section1
```

Route:

```
Route::get('users', ['as' => 'users.index','uses' => 'UsersController@index']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{ url('users')}}#Section1">Section1</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="{{ url('users#Section1') }}>Section1</a>
```

Comment: Just tried. Links are generated perfectly too with what you suggested `http://example.com/users#section1` , but the problem is when I click that link and I'm redirected to the users page, slash is added anyways `http://example.com/users#/section1`

Comment: Try clearing the cache in your browser (refresh using Ctrl+F5).
Maybe the apache config is conflicting, could you post the contents of your apache config file?

Comment: What should look for in `httpd.conf`? I don't have any `RewriteRule` or `DirectorySlash`, I have this `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public
</VirtualHost>`